# Azure Subscriptions are missing on a pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I am creating an Azure pipeline in DevOps. In the Azure App Service Deploy task, I selected connection type Azure Resource Manager. But Azure Subscription dropdown is empty.
And no Manage button next to it:

[image]

What can I be missing?

Comment: did you use the same identity sign in to Azure DevOps and in Azure Subscription, ? and what role of your ARM/Subscription to Azure App Service? since this is `integrated` MS services these are the basic checkpoints for you.

Comment: @Turbot I am not sure how to answer these questions. I do know that now I have ability to administer the CI/CD process.

Comment: simple question do you have Azure Subscription access with your logon in Azure DevOps ? if you don't know about it you need to understand how to access your Azure Subscriptions before managing/design the pipeline for this task.

Comment: For me, the existing subscription only appeared once I had created a new app in Azure Portal via 'App Services > Create New App Service'.

I had existing app services, but none of them had the framework version and platform that the DevOps pipeline was targeting. Once I had created a suitable App Service the subscription appeared in the list in the DevOps Pipeline dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press on "Manage":

[image]

Add your Azure subscriptions in the "New service connection" button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't have that "Manage" button (I added the picture to my original question).

Comment: Do you have permissions?

Comment: OK, now I do have ability to administer the CI/CD process. And yet I still don't have anything in the list of cubscriptions, and don't see the Manage button...

Comment: Check here which permissions you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

gonna love this UI, updated the screenshot

[image]