# Azure You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription. pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I signed on to a free-tier Azure subscription and am trying to create a CICD pipeline.

I go pipelines -> classic editor

[image]

Azure repo source --> docker container

[image]

but when starting to enter Azure subscription

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

I tried references from [Deploy azure subscription using azure devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267303/deploy-azure-subscription-using-azure-devops-pipeline), [Azure Subscriptions are missing on a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460146/azure-subscriptions-are-missing-on-a-pipeline), [You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription when creating new Kubernetes service connection in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73316384/you-don-t-appear-to-have-an-active-azure-subscription-when-creating-new-kubernet), and [Error when creating a pipeline. "You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631900/error-when-creating-a-pipeline-you-don-t-appear-to-have-an-active-azure-subscr) to no avail.

Azure's troubleshoot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops also gave me the same error, `You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription.`

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing?

Comment: Check if the troubleshooting steps provided in this [document](https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/troubleshooting-you-dont-appear-to-have-an-active-azure-subscription.html) helps to fix the issue.

Comment: That does not unfortunately help either @pravallika KV

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when trying to reproduce the issue. As an alternative way, I have configured the container service connection as below.
Go to Azure container registry and enable admin in Access keys and make a note of the username, password and login server.

[image]

Next, in azure devops, docker task, select the latest version (2) and fill in the required details as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

In the above screenshot, the docker registry is the ACR login server name and the docker ID is the ACR username.
Save and run the pipeline.
[image]

Comment: I got the following error `The pipeline is not valid. Job Job_1: Step  input containerRegistry references service connection undefined which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.` while trying your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestions, but I checked again today, and my Azure subscription populated the correct space.

Only thing I did was contact Azure and set up a meeting (which they did not show up for).

[image]